# "TypeError: container is undefined" when selecting element created with sceneBuilder using AggregatedView

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: container is undefined` thrown in a loop when I create a custom geometry.
Geometries are created using code from https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/custom-models-forge-viewer

I'm using the AggregatedView. The error does not occur when I instantiate a GuiViewer3D directly.

```
Uncaught TypeError: container is undefined
  getFragmentConsolidationType ConsolidationIterator.js:398
    updateRenderProxy ConsolidationIterator.js:416
    updateRenderProxy RenderModel.js:973
    updateSelectionProxies Viewer3DImpl.js:2145
    renderOverlays Viewer3DImpl.js:2152
    cmdRenderOverlays Viewer3DImpl.js:1330
    executeCommandList Viewer3DImpl.js:913
    tick Viewer3DImpl.js:1908
    animloop Viewer3DImpl.js:1939
```

Is this a bug in Autodesk Forge? Using version 7.80

Selecting a custom geometry with the AggregatedView. 
Expected the object to be selected.
Instead an error is thrown continuously.

Comment: Hi Adrian, I've been able to reproduce the issue locally, so this seems to be an issue in the viewer indeed. Let me report it to the engineering team, and I'll get back to you here as soon as we have any feedback.

Comment: Btw is this something that was working for you before? Or is it the first time you're actually trying to use the `SceneBuilder` extension in the context of an `AggregatedView` app?

Comment: Hi, thanks Petr! This is my first time attempting this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The engineering team confirmed that this is a problem with the `SceneBuilder` extension not being compatible with "model consolidation" - a process where multiple meshes are merged into a single GPU buffer to improve rendering performance. The `AggregatedView` class consolidates models automatically, which is why you're running into this issue.

While we are *not* planning to add consolidation support to models generated by the `SceneBuilder` extension, we will update the extension and make sure that this combination is handled gracefully. In the meantime, if you need to use `SceneBuilder` models in an `AggregatedView` app, please unconsolidate your custom models using `model.unconsolidate()`.

Comment: Thanks Petr, the error does not occur when using `model.unconsolidate()`

Comment: Update: The issue is fixed by updating to Forge viewer 7.82